# Why redirect to a specific route doesn't work?

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, routes

Here is my code:

```
$msg = 'successfully inserted';
Redirect::route('home')->with($msg);
```

Lines above are at the end of my script, but nothing happens. I mean `insert` query works as well but won't be redirect to `home` page. Noted that I have this line in the top of my script too:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
```

Any idea how can I make it working?

Comment: return redirect()->action('HomeController@index')->with($msg);

Comment: What is your Controller file and method? Replace HomeController with your Controller and index with your method.

Comment: Try: `return redirect('home')->with($msg);`

Comment: @HirenGohel Thank you, the problem was lack of `return`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like:

```
return redirect('home')->with($msg);
```

This will return you back to the `'home'` route!

Check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#redirects).

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Try code like this

```
redirect()->to('/home')->with($msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect with message like below:

```
$msg = 'successfully inserted';
return redirect()->action('HomeController@index')->with(compact('msg'));
// Replace HomeController with your Controller and index with your method.
```

Make sure your Route will look like below:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

Follow below link to know more about Laravel Redirects:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/redirects